# Search within a bounded box on a related model using Geocoder Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geocoding

In my search action, I am building up a query to list activities.  I would like to be able to limit those to activities whose location is within 5 miles of a centre point and order the activities by distance from centre point.

Its simple enough to get a list of locations:

```
Location.within_bounding_box(Geocoder::Calculations.bounding_box([location[:latitude], location[:longitude]], 20))
```

but how can i search the activities model using bounding_box and order by distance?